# Unable to download a file using drag&drop

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, google-chrome, url

I've been downloading images from the Internet doing drag&drop while holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Using Google Chrome, and of course Nautilus, it used to work fine. But I recently had problems with packages and now every time I do that a warning menu appears showing this message:

> The specified location is not supported

Probably I removed the packaged which allowed me to download content... can anybody help me?

Note: Downloading doing right-click works, but I use more drag&drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself reinstalling the system. Now drag&drop works fine!